# What's the name for a distribution where at the extreme there are more values farther away from the mean than closer?

Tags: distributions, distribution-identification

The image below from [this blog](https://juliasilge.com/blog/salary-gender/) provides a good example. I'm talking about distributions that are roughly Gaussian except that there are more values at the high end that would be expected. In particular, there are more values at, say three standard deviations above the mean than there are at two. In the image below there are more people who make 1M than 500k.

[image]

Comment: Some sort of [mixture distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) maybe?